# PriorityQueue cast to ArrayList in Java (Best Way??)

Tags: java

I have been investigating the best way to move an ArrayList to a PriorityQueue, and I have found that the best way to do it is by using the method pq.addAll(dataArrayList). But the problem I have now, is how to pass this PriorityQueue, pq, already ordered to the same previous DataArrayList.

The only way I can think of doing it is a structure that runs through the queue, and if the queue is not empty, it extracts and adds in dataArrayList.

```
public void sort2(Comparator<Router> comp){
    PriorityQueue<Router> pq = new PriorityQueue<Router>(comp);
    pq.addAll(datos);
    datos.clear();
    while(!pq.isEmpty()) {
        datos.add(pq.poll());
    }

}
```

Router is an ArrayList of Strings(it is actually a class with ip address, city, identifier, but so that we understand each other better we treat it as a String), for example ["a","c","b"] and sort by LessOrder --> ["a","b","c"].

It works, but is it the best way to implement this? Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to just sort the `ArrayList`? What's the meaning of the `PriorityQueue`, if you're not using it like one?

Comment: Yes, but I am analyzing three ways of sorting, using the default method, using a priority queue and finally, using Heap. Then I will undergo performance tests for large input sizes to analyze them in depth.

Comment: Well then your code is the simplest version. `PriorityQueue` doesn't offer any mass retrieve operations (except going through `spliterator()`, which would likely to be slower). Also, internally `PriorityQueue` is implemented as a heap.